# web3 RPC connection terminates program w/out an output

Tags: javascript, async-await, web3js

I have a simple NodeJS program to demonstrate my question

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
var provider = new HDWalletProvider("MY MNEMONIC", "HTTP://BAD_CONNECTION.127.0.0.1:7545");
var web3 = new Web3(provider);

(async function getCoinBase() {
    try {
        var coinbase = await web3.eth.getCoinbase();
        console.log('passed');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('failed');
        console.log(err);
    }
}())
```

I am using: 
"truffle-hdwallet-provider": "0.0.6",
"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.36"

When I run this program, neither "passed" nor "failed" gets printed to the screen The program just ends. I don't understand what is happening, how can the program just end w/out an error (entering the catch block and printing failed) or continue and printing "passed".

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcoinbase) for this method says, you have to provide callback method or use `web3.eth.coinbase` property to do it synchronously. Your example could look like below:

```
(async function getCoinBase() {
    try {
        web3.eth.getCoinbase(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("web3.eth.getCoinbase error = " + err);
            } else {
                console.log("web3.eth.getCoinbase " + result);
            }
        });
        console.log('passed');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('failed');
        console.log(err);
    }
}())
```

Probably, you have received runtime error but you did not notice it.